# Evaluate $ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln(1+e^x)}{x} $

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have intuitively guessed that the answer should be 1 as $x\to +\infty$. How do I formally prove this? Also how do I evaluate the limit as $x\to -\infty $.

UPDATE: Based on the answers below, I have managed to do the following.
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln (1+e^x)}{x} \\
= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln e^x(\frac{1}{e^x}+1)}{x} \\
= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x +\ln (\frac{1}{e^x}+1)}{x} \\
= \lim_{x\to\infty} 1+ \ln (1+\frac{1}{e^x})^\frac{1}{x} \\
$$
How do I proceed proceed from here?

Comment: How does intuition work differently with $ -\infty ?$

Comment: You can conclude since $\ln (\frac{1}{e^x}+1)\to 0$

Comment: Thanks. Silly of me to not notice something obvious. Anyway I did like the solution given by @trancelocation, though it requires a logical jump away from the question at hand and then come back.

Comment: @VishalSubramanyam Yes it is  a nice solution by squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $x\rightarrow +\infty$:
$$1 = \frac{\ln e^x}{x} \leq \frac{\ln (1+e^x)}{x} \leq \frac{\ln (2e^x)}{x}=1+\frac{\ln 2}{x} \stackrel{x\rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow}1$$

For $x\rightarrow -\infty$:
$$x=\ln y \Rightarrow \lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}\frac{\ln (1+e^x)}{x} = \lim_{y\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\ln (1+y)}{\ln y} = 0$$

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Write $$\ln(1+e^x)=\ln\left(e^x\left(1+\frac{1}{e^x}\right)\right)=x+\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{e^x}\right)$$

Answer (score 5):

Note that

$$ \frac{\ln(1+e^x)}{x}=\frac{\ln e^x+\ln(1+1/e^x)}{x}=\frac{x+\ln(1+1/e^x)}{x}$$

Based on your work, from here

$$...= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x +\ln (\frac{1}{e^x}+1)}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty} 1+ \frac{ \ln (\frac{1}{e^x}+1)}{x}=1$$

indeed

$$\ln \left(\frac{1}{e^x}+1\right)\to \ln 1=0$$

Comment: Gimusi.Thanks.Almost congruent with translocation, I delete.

Comment: Since you have made it honestly by your self you can also let in my opinion.

Comment: Gimusi, thanks for your opininon, deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Since you would get $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$

You can use l'hopital's rule:

$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln(1+e^x)}{x}=\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}=\frac{1}{e^{-x}+1}=1$

Formal proof of this relies on the proof of this case for l'hopital's rule.

Add on: for $-\infty$, solution should be trivial, treat $-\infty$ as an extended real number and substitute.

Comment: That's more unique ...

Comment: I think you didn't notice the tag "limits without L'Hospital "